# Looking for a room in US

Tags: accommodation, california

I'll be moving from Poland to California for 5 months internship. I was looking for rooms or flats in the area on facebook and craiglist. What I found a little strange is that literally nobody agreed to show me the property on a video call. They either said that currently they are not around or simply stopped answering. Is there any reasonable way to minimize the risk of running into a scam, since I'm not around and would have to wire money online beforehand? Some landlords offered to show me their driving license, is that a proof of anything?

Comment: Can you wait till you are there and can see the property in person? (Stay in a hotel or hostel for the first week or so.)

Comment: I would consider @Willeke's suggestion.  It makes the move more stressful and more hectic as well as more expensive, but it reduces the chance of being stuck with a bad lease for a property that you haven't seen.  Of course, only you can say whether the investment in a hotel room and having more to do when you arrive is justified by the reduction in risk.

Comment: Stay in an AirBnb for a week or so while you search?

Comment: Where in California? Some area in CA have the highest rents in the world and others are  much more affordable. Best strategy depends on the location.

Comment: In some places demand is so much higher than offer that landlords have very little incentive to make any effort. In others there lay be a much more level playing field. If you are moving to the Bay Area… good luck!

Comment: I'm kinda nervous that I won't be able to find anything in a week while staying in a hostel...
@Hilmar Santa Barbara area

Comment: As a general observation,  places with tight housing markets tend to have a lot of scams and such like. If you have a friend there, maybe ask them to check out the place. Maybe there's even a way to pay someone local a few bucks for their gas etc. to check things out if you don't know anyone.

Comment: Have you asked the company that you are an intern with if they have any accommodation contacts they can recommend?

Comment: @user10768. Ouch. Santa Barbara is difficult: very expensive and pretty far away from anything else. Try Goleta. Maybe check with UCSB (university) or Santa Barbara City College. SB has a large student population: if your internship is during summer break maybe some student housing frees up or you can sub-let. And yes, ask your employer for advise. I used to work for a company that is  headquartered in SB and recruiting was good about assisting interns.